# on click the result appears then auto refreshes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
document.querySelector('.login').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const check = document.querySelector('.username').value;
  console.log(typeof check);

  if (!check) {
    document.querySelector('.errorMessage').textContent =
      'kindly enter your username';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="user-login">
  <form>
    <label for="">User Name :  <input type="text" name="userName" class=" username"></label> <br>
    <label for="">Password:  <input type="password" name="" class="password"></label> <br>
    <button class="login">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="errorMessage">
  <label for=""></label> <br>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it's a classic question. Submitting a form reloads the page automatically. Pretty dumb default behaviour if you ask me. You want to add [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your html modify the button like this:

```
<button type="button" class="login">Login</button>
```

or in your javascript you can do something like this:

```
document.querySelector('.login').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Add this after set 'e' as parameter
    const check = document.querySelector('.username').value;
    console.log(typeof check);

    if (!check) {
       document.querySelector('.errorMessage').textContent =
       'kindly enter your username';
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh that's right, I always forget about the `type="button"` trick instead of `type="submit"`

Comment: thanks a lot i had resulted to not having it in a <form> tag but with your prompt it's working properly thanks a lot

Comment: If this helped you, if you don't mind to accept the answer so others can benefit from this too. Thanks a lot

Comment: i have done that thanks a lot hopefully i can learn more